# How do I create a JPA query to return objects in descending order of the number of remote references?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a @OneToMany relationship from Category.comparisons to Comparison.category (and a @ManyToOne relationship in the other direction).

My Comparison object has a "date" field, and my Category object has a boolean "safe" field.

I want to retrieve the 10 Category objects that have the most comparisons after a date that I pass into the query, and where Category.safe is true.

Here is my best effort, but it doesn't work at all:

```
SELECT c FROM Category c JOIN Category.comparisons 
  WHERE c.safe = true AND c.comparisons.date > :afterDate 
  ORDER BY COUNT(Category.comparisons) DESC
```

I could do this easily enough in native MySQL but I'm having real trouble getting my head around how JPA handles foreign-key references, and various other differences in syntax between SQL and the JPA query language.

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the size() function in the ORDER BY clause and correct the JOIN to use the previously defined alias `c` (for Category) and give it another alias `co`. Use that alias in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT c FROM Category c JOIN c.comparisons co
 WHERE c.safe = true AND co.date > :afterDate 
 ORDER BY size(c.comparisons) DESC
```

Please note however, that this will give you each category as many times as there are comparisons that match the criteria. The simplest way to avoid that is to use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c JOIN c.comparisons co
 WHERE c.safe = true AND co.date > :afterDate 
 ORDER BY size(c.comparisons) DESC
```

Again, please note that you should know what you are doing when applying DISTINCT as more data is accessed than the query reveals which may lead to performance issues later on.

Answer (score 1):

My JPA joins look as follows:

```
SELECT b FROM Befund b JOIN b.befundgruppe g WHERE g.idbefundgruppe = ?1
```

Notice the alias g for the joined table. Maybe this helps

For debugging purposes you could add the following to your persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
</properties>
```

inside the `persistence-unit` element. Then look into the log to see how the JPA is translated to SQL.

Best Regards

Comment: As the OP uses Hibernate (according to the tag), the property for debugging purposes would be "hibernate.show_sql" with a value of "true".